# jQuery textillate.js, hide text before animation. Solution doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I'm using the plugin jQuery textillate.js (https://github.com/jschr/textillate) to animate some text. It's going great, but the text is visible before animation. I've attempted the solution found at [How do i hide content before calling a jquery text effect plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183089/how-do-i-hide-content-before-calling-a-jquery-text-effect-plugin)

But it doesn't seem to work.

CSS:

```
.hide-text {
visibility:hidden;}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
$('.hide-text').textillate({
    selector: '.texts',
    loop: false,
    initialDelay: 3000,
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInDown',
            sync: true,
        },
    autoStart: true,
});
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="hide-text texts">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your (slighty modified) code seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/7KJkM/

```
.hide-text {
 visibility:hidden;
}

$('.texts').textillate({
    loop: false,
    initialDelay: 3000,
    in: {
        effect: 'fadeInDown',
        sync: true,
    }
});
```

Something else must be going on to cause the text not to be hidden. Is another css rule overriding the hide-text rule?